# How to access cloud storage data from backend?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm building an android app that uses an google app engine backend.

I have some audio files in a bucket on the google cloud storage (uploaded manually) and I want to access them from my backend (I want to get their Urls and send them to my app, so it can play the audio files).

My problem is that I can't understand how to access those files from the backend, is there any specific API for that? Meaning an API that allows the servlet to easily retrieve the data stored in the cloud storage.

thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, App Engine has a [Google Cloud Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/).

Comment: Thanks!
Do you have an example of how to use this library just to access data in my bucket? I didn't find anything that worked for me... :(